# What's difference between objective and subjective pronouns

Tags: grammar, pronouns

I like David as much as her

I like David as much as she

Dose the first sentence conveys the meaning?

I like david exactly same her

And the second one

I like David as much as she does David

Comment: @Jon I like david as much as her" means. I like david as much as I like her. I like David as much as she, describes I like as much as she likes david. is it correct or not?

Comment: I assume you meant to post this after Jon's answer. I'll spell it out. (1) 'I like David as much as her' is acceptable, but needs context to disambiguate the two possibilities. (2) 'I like David as much as she' is getting on for unacceptable nowadays. But some books on grammar are still in existence that recommend these archaic forms.  (3) 'I like David as much as she does' is acceptable and unambiguous. (4) 'I like David as much as I like her' is acceptable and unambiguous.

Answer (score 3):

“I like David as much as her” can be interpreted in two ways: “I like David as much as *she likes David*” and “I like David as much as *I like her*”. “I like David as much as she” sounds somewhat formal or old-fashioned; you would generally say “I like David as much as *she does*”, as in your second example.

*“I like David exactly same her” is incorrect. It should be “I like David exactly *the* same *as* her”.